# scipy.signal - filter an image with radially symmetric bandpass

Tags: python, scipy, filtering

I have the task of performing 'arbitrary' Fourier filtering of images - butterworth, bessel, and other types of low/high/band pass and reject filters.  A naive implementation:

```
# b, a are the result of scipy.signal.bessel or .butter, etc
# lfilter could be filtfilt too
filt_y = signal.lfilter(b, a, img, axis=0)
filt_both = signal.lfilter(b, a, filt_y, axis=1)
```

will impart an effect along a cross passing the origin in k-space, but leave the corner regions untouched.  Is there a way to still use scipy.signal to do this, but with annuli for the in and out of band regions?  I don't want a DoG or other type of kernel-based filter as found in cv2, but a causal filter as implemented in scipy.signal.

In principal, all that is needed is to be able to pass in the frequency value, np.sqrt(fxx ** 2 + fyy ** 2), for each sample but I can't see how to do this in the signal API.